# How do I dynamically enable/ disable a button based on the value inside a textbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would to enable a button if the value inside the textbox is equal to 'mypassword'. if the value inside the textbox is not equal to 'mypassword' I would like to disabale this button. I have tried the code below but it is not working for some reason.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const buttonElement = document.querySelector('submit')
        const inputElement = document.querySelector('password')
        inputElement.addEventListener('change'), (e) => {
            if (e.target.value.includes('mypassword')) {
                buttonElement.disabled = false
            } else {
                buttonElement.disabled = true
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <form action="review.php">

        <label for="">Password: </label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="password">

        <button type="submit" id='submit' class='submit'>Review Report</button>

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `e.target.value === 'mypassword'` ?

Comment: Note that you don't want to do passwords checks client side. Anyone can look into your source code to see what the password should be. You also seem to wanting to use jQuery but are not using jQuery at all?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava that isn't the problem. He is missing the second parm to the event listener because of an extra closing parentheses. `inputElement.addEventListener('change'), (e) => {`  The callback function isn't inside the addEventListener call.

Comment: Your first issue is simply that your code runs in the `head` before the elements exist.  You can confirm this by checking `buttonElement == null`.   Move your code to just before `</body>` *or* use [document ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).   Second issue is typos/code issues that others have pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your `addEventListener` call. The callback function isn't inside the `addEventListener` call.   Also I believe you want to listen to keyup events not change events.

```js
const buttonElement = document.querySelector('#submit')
const inputElement = document.querySelector('#password')


inputElement.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  if ( e.target.value.includes('mypassword')) {
    buttonElement.disabled = false
  } else {
    buttonElement.disabled = true
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
 
</head>

<body>

    <form action="review.php">

        <label for="">Password: </label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="password">

        <button type="submit" id='submit' class='submit' disabled>Review Report</button>

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Also, you can simplify your event handler to this if you want to.

```
const buttonElement = document.querySelector('#submit')
const inputElement = document.querySelector('#password')

inputElement.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  buttonElement.toggleAttribute('disabled', !(e.target.value.includes('mypassword')));
})
```